# How to check if key exist in values and values in key in Python

Tags: python, loops, dictionary, iteration

I need help with iterating through the dictionary. This might be not so smart way to do, but I need to try.

I have a dict like this:

```
{'a': 'b', 
 'b': 'c', 
 'c': 'd', 
 'm':'n', 
 'p':'r', 
 'r': 't'}
```

Wha I need as output, it could be dict or dataframe:

```
'a' : ['b', 'c', 'd'], 
'b' : ['c', 'd'],
'c': ['d'],
'm': ['n'],
'p': ['r', 't'],
'r': ['t']
```

I have tried with:

```
dict_output = {}
for k, v in my_dict.items():
    lista = []
    for ki, va in my_dict.items():
        if v in ki:
            lista.append(va)
    dict_l.update({k:lista})
```

But this only iterate for one time, I don't know how to iterate all over again until a break of the chain.

Edit:
[image]

Comment: Dictionaries are not meant to be ordered.. The output you're expected assume a certain order in which the items are seen while iterating.

Comment: @Abhishek Is this better to do from a dataframe? I created this dictionary from two columns I had in df

Comment: This is a graph traversal problem.  `dict` is not a good representation, although it's not horrid.  However, you might use the `graph` package.  At least look up "Python graph" and general graph traversal algorithms to give you the tools you need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define a small function (say, `get_key`) to recursively traverse your dictionary (say, `oct)` and `yield` keys one by one:

```
def get_key(dct, key):
    while key in dct:
        key = dct[key]
        yield key
```

Now, build your new dictionary by calling `get_key` inside a dict comprehension.

```
{k : list(get_key(dct, k)) for k in dct}
{'a': ['b', 'c', 'd'],
 'b': ['c', 'd'],
 'c': ['d'],
 'm': ['n'],
 'p': ['r', 't'],
 'r': ['t']}
```

---

**Handling Cycles**
Note that this is not going to terminate if your "graph" has cycles (a: b and b: a). You can fix this by maintaining a set of `visited` nodes:

```
def get_key_handle_cycles(dct, key):
    visited = set()
    while key in dct and key not in visited:
        visited.add(key)
        key = dct[key]

        yield key
```

And call this function the same way.

Comment: Thanks. But I'm getting TypeError: unhashable type: 'list' for line visited.add(key)

Comment: @jovicbg Does `dct` have lists in the value? This will not work then, because your question didn't indicate it had to handle those kinds of values in the input.

Comment: No, it has not lists in input, just two columns from dataframe with strings transformed to dict as key:value pairs.

Comment: @jovicbg Whatever you have to do, please make sure your input is _exactly_ as described in the question. Or else, figure out how to do so... or open a question if you can't.

Comment: I have edited my question, added screenshot. Pasted dict from a question and run, there is now empty lists. Thank you for helping.

Comment: @jovicbg Oops, there was a copy paste bug. Check again please?

Comment: @jovicbg No problem.